# Check if Vlan is accesible through the firewall

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, vlan

I want to check if a Vlan (10.253.240.11) is accesible to Our network thorugh the firewall. I've logged into the fw through Linux console, I run the command route -n | grep 10.253.240.
To find out what Interface it's on. I get answare back that it is on a Interface in the firewall, does this mean I should be able to Reach this vlan on the network, or is there another commando to check this?

Comment: If an interface on the firewall has that address range configured, it's likely that the firewall can route that subnet. The firewall rules may prohibit traffic from being routed to/from that network; it may not be reachable. What **exactly** do you mean by "reach this vLAN on the network" - what specific problem are you trying to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a ping on a machine within that subnet.
If ICMP is disabled on the firewall, ping and traceroute commands won't work.
If you want to check a specific service, try accessing a remote machine on that port with nmap.